# PowerShell issues with spaces in directory names

Tags: windows, git, powershell, perl

PowerShell has issues with spaces in directory names.

I am trying to execute a file in the same directory as the PS1 script like so:

```
.\getGravatarsForGource.pl
```

It works fine when the directory names do not have spaces in them (I changed the folder from `Git` to `Git stuff` on purpose) and I don't know how to make it execute correctly.

I could just change the folder name back to `Git`, what it was before, but it is an issue I want to solve because other people downloading my repository may not want to rework their entire filesystem so that they have no spaces in their directories.

FYI: Yes, I also tried it like `".\getGravatarsForGource.pl"`

**Output of PowerShell**

```
The term 'D:\Joshua\!Coding\Git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:22
+ D:\Joshua\!Coding\Git <<<< stuff\centaur-XML-Tool\gource\executables\run-gource-for-windows.ps1
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\Joshua\!Coding\Git:String) [], CommandNotFoundEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: The path isn't hard coded anywhere, is it?

Comment: Errors do not expand variables. So that error indicates that the path is in the code as a string literal. Put quotes around it in the code.

Comment: You may need single-quotes instead of double-quotes. Try this: `'D:\Joshua\!Coding\Git stuff\centaur-XML-Tool\gource\executables\run-gource-for-windows.ps1'` or this `Set-Location 'D:\Joshua\!Coding\Git stuff\centaur-XML-Tool\gource\executables\';.\run-gource-for-windows.ps1`